# can not build vmware 10 modules because of kernel version

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, vmware

I installed vmware workstation 10 on my Lubuntu 16.10 32bit with kernel version 4.8.0-22-generic. First, when I started workstation, it would request complining some modules. But this always failed. I checked the net regarding the issue and I was required to patch vmnet thing. I did, but when I run `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` the build fails, here is the output of the build

```
root@laho-VPCEA27FX:/home/laho# vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.h:33:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.c:31:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_kernel.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.c:27:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:39:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:82:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from ./include/asm-generic/bug.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/bug.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/mmdebug.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:8,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:39:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:46:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘cleanup_module’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:409:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    if (misc_deregister(&linuxState.misc)) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
At top level:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1342:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/task.o
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIFGetUserPages’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define current get_current()
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1127:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘current’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, (unsigned long)uvAddr,
                            ^~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define current get_current()
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1127:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘current’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, (unsigned long)uvAddr,
                                     ^~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct mm_struct *’
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1127:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, (unsigned long)uvAddr,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: declared here
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIF_EstimateLockedPageLimit’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1620:47: error: ‘NR_ANON_PAGES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    unsigned int anonPages = global_page_state(NR_ANON_PAGES);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1620:47: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:39:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:40:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:17,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmmon.ko' failed
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:45:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/driver.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_basic_defs.h:696:0: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
 #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \

In file included from ./include/linux/random.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/net.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:29,
                 from ./include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/ethtool.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:42,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/driver.c:32:
./include/linux/once.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)           \

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/driver.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/driver.c:23:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:45:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_basic_defs.h:696:0: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
 #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \

In file included from ./include/linux/random.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/net.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:29,
                 from ./include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/ethtool.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:42,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:29:
./include/linux/once.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)           \

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:23:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:45:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_basic_defs.h:696:0: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
 #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \

In file included from ./include/linux/random.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/net.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:29,
                 from ./include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/ethtool.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:42,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:29:
./include/linux/once.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)           \

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:23:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c: In function ‘VNetHubFindHubByID’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:132:49: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘idNum’ will return size of ‘uint8 * {aka unsigned char *}’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
         memcmp(idNum, currHub->id.pvnID, sizeof idNum))) {
                                                 ^~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:128:26: note: declared here
 VNetHubFindHubByID(uint8 idNum[VNET_PVN_ID_LEN]) // IN: PVN id to find
                          ^~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:132:49: warning: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘__builtin_memcmp’ call is the same expression as the first source; did you mean to provide an explicit length? [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
         memcmp(idNum, currHub->id.pvnID, sizeof idNum))) {
                                                 ^~~~~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:2:0,
                 from ./include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h:34,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:19,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:25:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c: In function ‘VNetHubAlloc’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:315:36: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘id’ will return size of ‘uint8 * {aka unsigned char *}’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
   memcpy(hub->id.pvnID, id, sizeof id);
                                    ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h:182:48: note: in definition of macro ‘memcpy’
 #define memcpy(t, f, n) __builtin_memcpy(t, f, n)
                                                ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:260:13: note: declared here
       uint8 id[])    // IN: PVN ID to use (NULL if allocPvn == FALSE)
             ^~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:2:0,
                 from ./include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h:34,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/uapi/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:56,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:19,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:25:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/hub.c:315:36: warning: argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘__builtin_memcpy’ call is the same pointer type ‘uint8 * {aka unsigned char *}’ as the destination; expected ‘uint8 {aka unsigned char}’ or an explicit length [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
   memcpy(hub->id.pvnID, id, sizeof id);
                                    ^
./arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h:182:48: note: in definition of macro ‘memcpy’
 #define memcpy(t, f, n) __builtin_memcpy(t, f, n)
                                                ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:45:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_basic_defs.h:696:0: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
 #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \

In file included from ./include/linux/random.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/net.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:29,
                 from ./include/linux/if_ether.h:23,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:27:
./include/linux/once.h:37:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)           \

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)

In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/printk.h:110:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c: In function ‘UserifLockPage’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define current get_current()
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:116:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘current’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, addr,
                            ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:52,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define current get_current()
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:116:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘current’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, addr,
                                     ^~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct mm_struct *’
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:117:10: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       1, 1, 0, &page, NULL);
          ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: expected ‘struct page **’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:116:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’
    retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, addr,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1315:6: note: declared here
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2253:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c: In function ‘VNetNetIf_Create’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
                                                                ^
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c: In function ‘VNetNetifStartXmit’:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:464:7: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’; did you mean ‘mem_start’?
    dev->trans_start = jiffies;
       ^~
At top level:
/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.c:85:1: warning: ‘VNetNetIfSetup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 VNetNetIfSetup(struct net_device *dev)  // IN:
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-WyKnVU/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

I know this is because of a too new kernel version for vmware 10. Can anyone please show me the work around this? How to make it compatible with the new kernel?